# security issue: php login/logout script + back button

Tags: php, session, back-button

I am using a login script that stores a session value

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'yes'
```

when user enters correct user/password. On logout, this session value is set to  blanks.  However user can hit back buttin a few times and get logged back in.  I have also tried  $_SESSION = array(); and  session_destroy(); but with same results.

Comment: I am thinking of putting a random ID number in a session value at login and writing it to the database. On logout, clear the session value and the record in database.  If user hits back button after logout, no match can be made against user value in database, so program will force user back to login.

Answer (score 1):

Do they really get logged back in, or are they just reloading pages from their browser cache? If it's just the cache, they will not be able to see a page they did not previously visit, and they will not be able to see new data on your site.

If they are really getting logged back in, then your login code is bad. Post the login code and the login test you do on each page.

Answer (score -2):

my bad. code was in error. thanks... I cleared caches & cookies.
Now IE lets me backup and assume old session value.
Firefox won't let me baqck in.